# SQL Server : comparing boolean expression results

Tags: boolean, sql-server-2012

I have a query that tells me when a client has not communicated with our server in the last hour. When that happens, I need to send an email.

This is the query that retrieves all of the clients that haven't communicated in time.

```
SELECT * FROM Client 
    WHERE DATEADD(HOUR, 1, LastCommunication) < GetDate()
```

However, if a client has not communicated in days, I only want to send one single email. I also want to send an email when a previously broken client comes back online. For this purpose, I added a bit column in the table named "IsErrorNotified".

I want to only get the clients whose error state has changed. Normally, I would do this :

```
SELECT * FROM Client 
    WHERE DATEADD(HOUR, 1, LastCommunication) < GetDate() = IsErrorNotified
```

However, this doesn't work. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks simpler than the expression you have;

```
SELECT * FROM Client
WHERE CASE WHEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GetDate()) > LastCommunication 
           THEN  IsErrorNotified ELSE ~IsErrorNotified END = 0;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f68b/6).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT * FROM Client 
    WHERE DATEADD(HOUR, 1, LastCommunication) < GetDate()
        AND IsErrorNotified = 1
```

but it is good to use `sargable` predicate

```
SELECT * FROM Client 
    WHERE LastCommunication < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GetDate())
        AND IsErrorNotified = 1
```

Comment: no, I really need to do an equality check between the bit value and the result of "<" operator. I just thought I might be able to use the XOR operator... I'm trying something right now.

Comment: Thanks for the sargable hint, I didn't think about that

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. What I'm looking to do is to compare the two boolean expressions to see if they give the same result. It's pretty much the same as doing a "NOT A XOR B", but this doesn't work either with SQL server. XOR seems to be a bitwise operator only...

Answer (score 0):

I had to work with some boolean logic equivalence to write the complete condition like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Client 
    WHERE (LastCommunication >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GetDate()) AND IsErrorNotified = 1) 
    OR (LastCommunication < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GetDate()) AND IsErrorNotified = 0)
```

I would still like to find a better way of doing a boolean XOR (which is the same a comparing booleans for equality) with SQL Server...